# Redirect after saving item via ModelForm

Tags: django, redirect, render, modelform

I'm using a modelform to add some items to one of my models.

in view I have :

```
def create_cf(request, fslug):
 detail = Fd.objects.get(slug=fslug)

 if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = CFForm(request.POST)
    if cf.is_valid():
        instancecf = cf.save()
        return redirect('cf:create_cf', fslug=fslug)
 else:
    cf = CFForm()
 return render(request, 'cf/create_cf.html', {'cf': cf})
```

template:

```
<form  action="/create_cf/" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{cf}}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

though, and unfortunately, I get a Page Not Found Errorat /create_cf.html... What am I doing wrong??

many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen at the *redirect*, or does this happen when rendering the page to submit values? Or because the `action="/create_cf/"` can not be found? Typically one uses a `{% url ... %}` at the `action="..."` attribute, and thus calculate the URL dynamically.

Comment: only with the redirect !

Comment: This could be happening because you aren't passing in arguments with your redirect, and create_cf takes an argument called fslug. Have you tried, return redirect('cf:create_cf', fslug=fslug)?

Comment: @Sam: thanks that is the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redirect to the same page in you are, it is correct?

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view the details of the object you're querying then you also need to pass it to the context.

Try This:

```
def create_cf(request, fslug):
 detail = Fd.objects.get(slug=fslug)

 if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = CFForm(request.POST)
    if cf.is_valid():
        instancecf = cf.save()
        return redirect('cf:create_cf')
 else:
    cf = CFForm()
 return render(request, 'cf/create_cf.html', {'cf': cf, 'detail': detail})
```

Comment: What do you mean with detail? I haven't defined this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

here is the  solution (thanks to Sam)

in view I have :

```
def create_cf(request, fslug):
 detail = Fd.objects.get(slug=fslug)

 if request.method == 'POST':
    cf = CFForm(request.POST)
    if cf.is_valid():
        instancecf = cf.save()
        return redirect('cf:create_cf', fslug=fslug)
 else:
    cf = CFForm()
 return render(request, 'cf/create_cf.html', {'cf': cf})
```

template:

```
<form  action="/create_cf/" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{cf}}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```